# How to re-use model pre-trained with multiple image categories on two image categories (binary)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I've trained my model in keras to classify images of food in 16 categories.
I've got 1000 samples per category. My model is doing pretty well in this case, with about 95% accuracy.
Now I want to reuse this model on the same set of images, but now brought to two categories (healthy and unhealthy).

I have tried to do this like this:

```py
model = load_model('model_saved.h5')
ll = model.layers[len(model.layers)-2].output
ll = Dense(1,activation="sigmoid",name="densehh_out")(ll)

model = Model(inputs=model.input,outputs=ll)
```

but accuracy starts on about 50% and won't pass 72%/

also loss acts pretty jumpy on my val_data.

Is there any better way to achieve better accuracy and convergent loss function?